# LHS is convergent iff RHS is convergent. Why? Achim Klenke Probability theorem 6.7

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The theorem goes: Let $A_{1}, A_{2} ... \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A_{N}$ increasing to $\Omega$ and $\mu (A_{N}) < \infty$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. For measurable $f, g: \Omega \xrightarrow{} E$ where $E$ is a metric space, define

$\tilde{d}(f, g) := \sum_{N = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-N}}{1 + \mu(A_{N})} \int_{A_{N}} \text{min}\{1, d(f(\omega), g(\omega))\} d\mu$.

Then $\tilde{d}$ is a metric that induces convergence in measure: if $f, f_{1}, ...$ are measurable, then $f_{n} \xrightarrow{} f$ in measure iff $\tilde{d}(f, f_{n}) \xrightarrow{} 0$.

In the proof, the author defines $\tilde{d}_{N}(f, g) = \int_{A_{N}} \text{min}\{1, d(f(\omega), g(\omega))\} d\mu$.

He says $\tilde{d}(f, f_{n}) \xrightarrow{} 0 $ iff $\tilde{d}_{N}(f, f_{n}) \xrightarrow{} 0 $ for all $N$. Why do we have this? First taking the infinite sum then taking the limit is the same as first taking the limit then sum? How to justify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\tilde{d}(f, g) $$ $$ = \sum_{N = m+1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-N}}{1 + \mu(A_{N})} \int_{A_{N}} \text{min}\{1, d(f(\omega), g(\omega))\} d\mu $$ $$+\sum_{N = 1}^{m} \frac{2^{-N}}{1 + \mu(A_{N})} \int_{A_{N}} \text{min}\{1, d(f(\omega), g(\omega))\} d\mu$$ and the first term is less than $\sum_{N = m+1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-N}}{1 + \mu(A_{N})}<2^{-m}$ since $1+\mu (A_N) \geq 1$. I hope you can complete the proof using this.

Comment: Thanks! I write it further based on this hint. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Thank @geetha290krm for your hint!

Following this hint, fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that

$\tilde{d}(f, f_{n}) \leq \frac{1}{2^{m}} + \sum_{N = 1}^{m}\frac{2^{-N}}{1 + \mu(A_{N})} \tilde{d}_{N}(f, f_{n})$.

Then, if all $\tilde{d}_{N}(f, f_{n})$ converges to zero, we have the limit of RHS is $1/2^{m}$. So by the definition of limit, for such $m$, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $n \geq k$, we have

RHS $\leq 1/2^{m} + 1/2^{m}$ where the first $1/2^{m}$ is the limit and the second serves as the $\epsilon$.

Then for $n \geq k$, LHS also is smaller than $1/2^{m} + 1/2^{m}$. $m$ can be arbitrarily large so the limit of LHS is zero.

If not all $\tilde{d}_{N}$ converges to zero then it's easy to see $\tilde{d}$ doesn't go to zero.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.